# Odd issue with generic function in Scala

Tags: scala, f#

I'm in the process of learning a bit about Scala in order to see how it compares to F#, which is what I spend most of my time with. I'm attempting a pretty straightforward memoization technique for functions. In F# I would use something like this:

```ml
open System.Collections.Generic

let memoize (f : 'a -> 'b) =
  // A dictionary in which to cache results of previous
  // calls of the function
  let dict = new Dictionary<'a, 'b>()

  let memoizedFunction input =
    match dict.TryGetValue(input) with
    | true,  x -> x
    | false, _ -> 
      let answer = f input
      dict.Add(input, answer)
      answer

  memoizedFunction
```

In attempting to produce an equivalent version of this in Scala I've come up with the following:

```
def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
  val dict = collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A, B]()

  def memoizedFunction[A, B](input: A): B = 
    dict.get(input) match {
      case x: Some[B] => x
      case _ =>
        val answer = f(input)
        dict += ((input, answer))
        answer
    }

  memoizedFunction _
}
```

I'm receiving a few errors in the REPL when I attempt to define this function:

```
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : input.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
               dict.get(input) match {
                    ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : input.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
                   val answer = f(input)
                              ^
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : input.type (with underlying type A)
 required: A
                   dict += ((input, answer))
                             ^
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type parameters on `memoizedFunction` shadow the outer type parameters. The nitty-gritty of Scala generics escapes me, but that's why input's type of A isn't the A that Scala is looking for.

Also, `x: Some[B]` conflicts with the return type of `memoizedFunction`, which is B. The idiomatic way to match Option is `Some(x) => // do something with x`.

So here's what I've got with those 2 things corrected:

```
def memoize[A, B](f: A => B): A => B = {
  val dict = collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A, B]()

  def memoizedFunction(input: A): B = 
    dict.get(input) match {
      case Some(x) => x
      case _ =>
        val answer = f(input)
        dict += ((input, answer))
        answer
    }

  memoizedFunction _
}
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks!